# How to publish-consume a message from IBM MQ using Message id or Correlation id in Mule4

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component

I need to correlate request and reply messages. I have a requirement to publish a message to MQ(REQUEST.QUEUE) and consume the reply message from the reply queue(REPLY.QUEUE). I am using MuleSoft IBM MQ publish-consume operation to publish the message. I am also specifying a reply queue in the publish-consume configurations because the reply comes into the reply queue. I also set the "request-reply-pattern" but it does not seem to be consuming the correct message.
My requirements are to publish a message with a unique id(message_id or correlation_Id) so I can consume the reply of that particular message using the same message_id or correlation_Id. I could use any custom Id but I need to make sure when I consume it, I am not consuming any random message off the reply queue. It has to be the reply message which was the result of my publish message. This is a sync process so I will need to send and receive the message that is associated with a particular transaction

Below are my configurations of the publish-consume operator. I am able to publish the message but the consumer is reading any random message that is already sitting in the reply queue.

```
<ibm-mq:publish-consume doc:name="Publish consume" doc:id="86294ec7-6559-427f-8c80-eafa4b458a50" requestReplyPattern="CORRELATION_ID" config-ref="IBM_MQ_Config" destination="REQUEST.QUEUE">
            <ibm-mq:message>
                <ibm-mq:reply-to destination="REPLY.QUEUE" />
            </ibm-mq:message>
                <ibm-mq:consume-configuration maximumWait="10" ackMode="IMMEDIATE" maximumWaitUnit="SECONDS" /></ibm-mq:publish-consume>
```

[Image of publish-consume configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3VCA.png)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the consumer of the published message is respecting the correlation id in the reply? What version of Mule 4 and the IBM MQ connector are you using?

Comment: I need to confirm with the MQ guys if they are doing anything with the correlation id. May be they are not returning it with the reply?. But I thought the Mule MQ connector takes care of it. I am using Mule runtime 4.4.0 and MQ version 1.6.13

Comment: It may depend on what the other side is doing with the message published. You could try enable the debug logs of the connector and/or the IBM MQ client libraries to confirm if the correlation ID is received in the reply.

Comment: I tried to add the debug logs but its not really showing the outgoing and incoming messages. Are these correct for enabling MQ debug logs:
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft.connectors.ibmmq" level="DEBUG"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.jms.commons" level="DEBUG"/>

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can have consume node in the same flow and pick the messages based on the correlationID.

```
<flow name="publish-consume-correlation-id">
  <ibm-mq:publish-consume config-ref="config"
    destination="targetDestination"
    requestReplyPattern="CORRELATION_ID">
    <ibm-mq:message >
      <ibm-mq:reply-to destination="replyToDestination" />
    </ibm-mq:message>
  </ibm-mq:publish-consume>
        
</flow>

<flow name="ibm-mq-listener-correlation-id" >
  <ibm-mq:listener config-ref="config" destination="replyToDestination">
    <ibm-mq:reply-to-response requestReplyPattern="CORRELATION_ID" />
  </ibm-mq:listener>
  
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for code sample. I'll try it out. But I am not understanding the point of using publish-consume if we can't consume in the same flow?. And what is the point of giving the replyToDestination then?. I can also use the regular MQ Publisher and provide replyToDestination. Looks like there is a bit of misunderstanding on the usage of these different MQ operators and mule documentation is not clear